# What are some cheap ways to measure high temperatures (2000+ Celcius)

Tags: temperature

I am trying to find some other ways to measure the temperature of an object that my thermal couple would have melted at long ago. But also doesn't cost upwards of $200 to implement.

Can you determine the temperature of an object from a regular image as opposed to one obtained by thermal imaging?

Maybe measuring laser diffraction through the air near the hot object?

What about if I just measure the temperature a certain distance away with my thermal couple where it will not melt and borrow a thermal camera to get the real temperature of the object and build a temperature correlation between them both - assuming that the environment between them is fairly steady state? This is probably the one I am capable of doing - does this seem reasonable?

Thanks.